# Input = time, How to allow input of only the hour. No minutes or seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow the user to input a time but only allow the input of hours, no minutes or seconds. I understand a text or number field would be better but need to post the input as a time.

I have tried setting the step attribute to 600, however that removes the milliseconds only.

Comment: Why not setup a text input with min and max between 0 and 23? At the end of your code you can create a Date object based on the other inputs or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to input as a time field. When posted because it is received as a DateTime Object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The step attribute is the step amount you can do in milliseconds, so in this case you should use `60 * 60 * 1000` (60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 1 hour) as the value:

```html
<input type="time" step="3600000" />
```

Note that this does not work in Safari, but I did test it in Chrome. Safari simply doesnt support this type at all, so no validation happens as far as I can see. Which makes this not universally compatible.

Comment: why don't use a datepicker instead? [jQuery Ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) or [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @Sim1-81 then you'd have to add jQuery(+Bootstrap) to the project. HTML5 has it's own datepicker

Comment: @LucaKiebel Indeed it does, that surprised me a bit too.. MDN says its the date in milliseconds as thats the underlying mechanism, but yeah, both work. Shouldnt be the case. What if I want to skip by a 1000 days? I know, how rarely does that happen, but who knows. Also, I agree, adding _more_ dependencies is not what you want if the browser/os already comes with a perfectly adequate datepicker that users are used to.

Comment: @Luca Kiebel because with jQuery or bootstrap you can specify date format that you prefer for the output of the picker. With the HTML5 only the start date , the end date and the steps

Comment: @Sim1-81 With Vanilla JS, your output is a simple `Date` object that you can format any way you want. No need to add a huge library with its own conventions if the browser already provides a way to accomplish it. Even if that way is slightly different from the one you are used to.

Comment: That is why coding is pretty, there is a lot of ways to do the same things. it's obvius that include a huge library for use only 1 method is not advisable

Comment: I don't think this works on chrome anymore.

Comment: @kohl Just tested it in the snippet on my chrome and it increments by an hour. The minutes are disabled even (I don't remember the default input looking this decent). Although indeed, it does allow you to use clicking to select minutes.

Comment: yes it does allow one to select minutes when they use their mouse and that is what I am talking about.

Comment: Can we validate it real time with no JS? So when user click the "time" icon. the time only show up hour

Answer (score 3):

When I tried to use code suggested in accepted answer, it didn't work for me as expected, so I just want to share my experience , if someone has same problem:

In my case I had no milliseconds in my input, so it was enough to do it like this:

```
<input type='time' step="3600" >
```