# Input Type Time to select only hours

Tags: javascript, html, input

Can I set input type time to just select hours, not to select minutes. I just want to select from and to for hours like 2:00 to 3:00 not with any minutes.

Comment: Here answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063185/input-time-how-to-allow-input-of-only-the-hour-no-minutes-or-seconds

Answer (score 3):

Use simple select tags as shown below:

```html
<label for="from">From: </label>
  <select name="from" id="from">
    <option value="1">1:00</option>
    <option value="2">2:00</option>
    <option value="3">3:00</option>
    <option value="4">4:00</option>
    <option value="5">5:00</option>
  </select>

  <label for="to">To: </label>
  <select name="to" id="to">
    <option value="1">1:00</option>
    <option value="2">2:00</option>
    <option value="3">3:00</option>
    <option value="4">4:00</option>
    <option value="5">5:00</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an input type="number" and adjust the values with attributes.. Like that:

```
<input type="number" id="yourId" name="yourName" min="1" max="24">
```

The user shoulb be able to input only numbers between 1 and 24 hours. To prettify your design you can use some label after the input field showing something like "Hour" to reference the plural.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `step` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

```html
<form>
  <input type="time" required step="3600">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Isn't this selecting minutes too whereas the OP specifically asked they want to select only hours

Comment: No. It imposes the constants that have been specified. 1) Use of `time` input. 2) Valid entries do not include minute values. Other answer ignore the requirement that input type=time be used.

Comment: *Valid entries do not include minute values*... yup, but this answer does include minitues. Isnt it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing something. 2:01 is an invalid input. 1:59 is an invalid input. 2:00 is a valid input.

Comment: hmm got it. The question appeared to me that `minutes` shouldn't even appear where it was just that they shouldn't be allowed to be selected. Thanks. that does answer this question, I guess.

Comment: thanks for your responses but with step="3600" actually let me select minutes also so didnt work

Comment: You can select minutes but it does not validate. The thing you want does not exist. You can write some JavaScript to reset the minutes to "00" ever time they change but minutes is part of `time` and thus will always be there.