# How do I modify the datetime-local input type?

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to modify this type so that it only shows hours. However, I can't and so instead it keeps involving minutes. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like someone else already had similar question. Hopefully this will help you: [Input = time, How to allow input of only the hour. No minutes or seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063185/input-time-how-to-allow-input-of-only-the-hour-no-minutes-or-seconds)