# Force user to enter only hours in Input=Time and disable Minutes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

In my application the Time will always be like HH/00/00. So users will only need to enter the hour value as the minutes will be 00. I could not find a way to change the format of the input=time to only HH.

I found some articles about assigning step value but it doesn't work.

Any idea about preventing users to select minutes and force him to only select hours?

```
<div class="md-form mx-5 my-5">
    </div>

  <label>Choose your time</label>
  <input type="time"  /
```

[image: Time]

Comment: Why not just use a `select`?  (or some fancy-UI version such as [tag:select2])

Comment: @freedomn-m do you mean use a select and add options to all the available hours ?

Comment: "all the available hours" - sounds like you think you need more than 24...

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your comment. I would do that but I'm asking if there is any way to just put like format=HH. if not, so I will use a select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some JS code ? a simple one really, like the one below, you can add more conditions to make it much more strict, but here you go:

```js
const timeInput = document.getElementById('time');

timeInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let hour = e.target.value.split(':')[0]
  e.target.value = `${hour}:00`
})
```

```html
<div class="md-form mx-5 my-5">
    </div>

  <label>Choose your time</label>
  <input id="time" type="time">
```

Comment: Thanks!. That's good. But minutes still appear to the user :). I don't know if it is possible to remove it from the timepicker

Comment: It is not possible, but it would not be cool, if there was a way to make only minutes input disabled, that would be cool, but showing only hours without minutes that would be ugly in my opinion, you can make a simple input or select with only hours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063185/input-time-how-to-allow-input-of-only-the-hour-no-minutes-or-seconds?rq=1
I found that, there is a way to make minutes disabled, here you go, but it is not universally compatible, my code works with every browser.